# Can a sound file be deleted after preload in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, audio, preloading

I'm building a website for my band and I want to build a music player so that people can listen to our recorded songs online. The only problem is that I use the `<audio>` tag to play sound. Apparently, it requires a source from file system (mp3 file for example), which exposes the original sound files to the open public, and the files can be downloaded etc. by examining the source code. This is a huge problem for copyright reasons and other that kind of things.

So I came up with this kind of idea to prevent abuse:
I request a file name with an `XMLHttpRequest` which can be fetched from database. Then I preload this sound file while showing "loading" sign for the viewer. After this comes the problem: is there any way of renaming the sound file instantaniously after preload and still play the sound correctly? That way no one could look up the file name from the source code, because it would've been changed by then. The name would ofcourse be an MD5-hash e.g. so it can't be guessed.

Hopefully you stayed on my train of thought. How does this sound? Are there any better solutions? I've heard something about Media Streaming Servers, but couldn't understand them. Is my solution possible in any way?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: DRM encoding is as close as you will get. Otherwise your file can be accessed though so many means, even playing alone can allow capture just via a screen recording device, even DRM cant avoid that. Welcome to the same problem every artist deals with online. Believe me when I tell you the brightest minds in media have tried to stop this, but they too have been _mostly_ unsuccessful. DRM is about as close as it gets

Comment: Any solution that relies on an `XMLHTTPRequest` with a long name is easily circumvented, because the browser network inspector in the dev tools will show the request URL.

Comment: @Madness Thanks for the answer! So how can I get started? Do you know any good tutorial or documentation on getting started with DRM (Google Widevine etc.)?

Comment: Have a lot of money and infrastructure for starters. I mean what is your budget for something like this? I have been tasked at a high level for FOX, MySpace, several (unnamed) adult video producers, and am myself a musician but again, I cannot stress enough that DRM is mostly laughable. It is only supported on Windows and OSX for [limited browsers (Widevine)](https://support.google.com/widevine/answer/2920794?hl=en&vid=1-635752543268640808-10311446603141181267) and even [more limited browsers (Silverlight)](http://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/locale/en-us/html/installation-win-SL5.html)

Comment: But if you are still determined to spend alot of money and waste alot of time chasing your tail, here are a couple of starting points: [Silverlight](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838192%28VS.95%29.aspx) and [Widevine](http://www.widevine.com/getting_started.html)

Comment: @Madness There's no budget :D I will thus abandon this idea. Maybe I'll use a Soundcloud embedding or something then....

Comment: That is what I assumed, and it is no knock against you. When I said the absolute biggest players have spent countless BILLIONS trying, I wasn't joking, and all they have is still a wonky system that at best is just a deterrent. It is out of reach for most content creators.